# Spring batch - use JdbcCursorItemReader to read from a DataSource and work with the ResultSet

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-batch

I'm trying to use Spring Batch to create a Job that uses a DataSource (configure before) and runs a query. 
I want to be able to iterate through the returned ResultSet to create a new table with the returned data.

I can create a reader like this, but i don´t know how to iterate the results.

```
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<ResultSet> reader(String query, DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<ResultSet> itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemReader.setSql(query);
    return itemReader;
}
```

What should my ItemProcessor receive? This?

```
public class ExtractionItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<ResultSet, String>{    
@Override
    public String process(ResultSet item) throws Exception {
        // transform the resultSet into a SQL INSERT
  }
}
```

EDIT: the only way I know the results of the query is by the ResultSet Metadata, so I can´t create a POJO and set the properties.

Comment: If it is that simple, don't use Spring Batch. Use a `JdbcTemplate` with a `RowCallbackHandler` and execute the insert. If you really want to use Spring Batch don't mess around with the results but return either an object or a map with the row results and use an `JdbcItemWriter` to do the inserts.

Comment: I currently do this from the ResultSet and it´s metadata. But I will work with thousands of rows, so I readed Spring Batch was efficient handling that and has jobs, to schedule this extractions

Comment: And where do I say you need a POJO? Yo can simply return a list of `Map`s instead of a results. You are currently using components for things they aren't supposed/designed to do.

Comment: I have tried to do this with a Map, but that way I can´t get the metadata of the table and I need that information to build the CREATE table statement.

Answer (score 1):

Create a POJO class to represent a record, such as `Foo`:

```
public class Foo {
     private final long id;
     // more properties

     public Foo(long id // ,...) {
         this.id = id;
         // set other properties
     }

     public long getId() {
         return id;
     }
}
```

so the reader will be a `JdbcCursorItemReader<Foo>`.

And create a `RowMapper<Foo>` such as:

```
public FooRowMapper implements implements RowMapper<Foo> {

    @Override
    public Foo mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        long id = rs.getLong("id");
        // more properties 
        return new Foo(id // more properties);
    }
}
```

and set it on the reader:  `itemReader.setRowMapper(new FooRowMapper())`.

The `ExtractionItemProcessor` will receive a `Foo`, and would look something like:

```
public class ExtractionItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Foo, String>{    
@Override
    public String process(Foo item) throws Exception {
    int someValue = transform(foo);
    return "INSERT INTO blah blah blah..." + someValue + "...";  // potentially dangerous - see SQL injection attack
  }
}
```

To take it further, perhaps `ExtractionItemProcessor` transformation of a `Foo` should create a `Bar`.  Then it would look like:

```
public class ExtractionItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Foo, Bar>{    
@Override
    public Bar process(Foo item) throws Exception {
    int someValue = transform(foo);
    // more values....
       return new Bar(someValue // more values);
  }
}
```

So then the `ItemWriter` impelementation will take a `List<Bar>`, which knows how to safely insert `Bar`s to another table.

Comment: I would create a POJO if I knew what data I would receive previously to execute the query, but i don't. The only way i know is from the ResultSet Metadata